# Error: orphaned default using case statement in Java

Tags: java

so here's my code, I'm trying to get the user to have to re-enter if they don't enter something that satisfies the previous cases. Any and all help appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
    boolean proj, flag;
    String rN, line, os = null;
    int cap = 0;

    int response = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Press: 1 to add a general purpose Room \n"
                + "Press: 2 to add a Computer Room \n"
                + "Press: 3 to display information about stored rooms \n"
                + "Press: 4 to display all rooms with projectors \n"
                + "Press: 5 to enter a number of attendees and display possible rooms. \n"
                + "Press: -1 to Exit");
        response = kb.nextInt();
        switch (response) {
            case 1:
                there is code here-
            case 3:
                there is code here-
            case 4:
                there is code here-
            case 5:
                there is code here-
            case 6:
                there is code here-

            default:
                System.out.println("Not understood. Re-enter");
                break;

                } while (response != -1);
        }
```

The error I'm given is orphaned default - and I've removed the code from the other cases because it won't let me ask otherwise.

Comment: do you have a "break" at the end of every "case"?

Comment: It would really help if you'd turn this into a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem (and indent your code more sensibly).

Comment: And there is a } missing before the "while".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though your while statement is in the wrong place which may cause the error.

```
 do {
    System.out.println("Press: 1 to add a general purpose Room \n"
            + "Press: 2 to add a Computer Room \n"
            + "Press: 3 to display information about stored rooms \n"
            + "Press: 4 to display all rooms with projectors \n"
            + "Press: 5 to enter a number of attendees and display possible rooms. \n"
            + "Press: -1 to Exit");

    response = kb.nextInt();
    switch (response) 
       {
            case 1:
                there is code here-
            case 3:
                there is code here-
            case 4:
                there is code here-
            case 5:
                there is code here-
            case 6:
                there is code here-
            case -1:
                System.out.println("Exiting program");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Not understood. Re-enter");
                break;
        }

    }while (response != -1);
```

Make sure it is at the end of the Do-While loop and not inside as it was before.

Comment: This will still show the "Not understood ..." when the user enters -1

Comment: I've updated it, I was more concerned with the syntax of the loop working. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int response = 0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Press: 1 to add a general purpose Room \n" + "Press: 2 to add a Computer Room \n"
                               + "Press: 3 to display information about stored rooms \n"
                               + "Press: 4 to display all rooms with projectors \n"
                               + "Press: 5 to enter a number of attendees and display possible rooms. \n"
                               + "Press: -1 to Exit");
            response = kb.nextInt();
            switch (response)
            {
                case 1:
                    //                        there is code here-
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //                        there is code here-
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //                        there is code here-
                    break;
                case 5:
                    //                        there is code here-
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //                        there is code here-
                    break;

                case -1:
                    System.out.println("Bye!");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Not understood. Re-enter");
                    break;

            }
        }
        while (response != -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this while having left-overs from:

**Converting a switch into an if-else block.**

Minimal example that gives "orphaned default" error:

```
  public static void whatever(){
      if( true ){      
          default: return; 
      };;
  };;
```